# Determine if any of a list of values occurs in a string, and return which one

Tags: c#

In C#, I'd like to search a string for any of a list of words, and return which one is found. I know I could loop through, but I'm curious if there is a simpler way.

Essentially there are 3 values which are 'permitted', but sometimes the values being read will have that value plus extraneous suffixes.

eg

```
string[] permittedValues = {"Historical Search","Correspondence","Archived"};
```

but the data being checked may be:

```
"Historical Search"            (should return "Historical Search")

"Correspondence Vol 2"  (should return "Correspondence")

"Archived - fileroom 3" (should return "Archived")

"sldfjslkdfjsdklfj"     (should return something allowing it to be handled)
```

I can do

```
bool isValidValue = permittedValues.Any(myString.Contains);
```

to see if any of the list appear, but I also need to get which one.

Hopefully that makes sense.

(Originally I had mistakenly put "Historical Search" as "Historical", so I have marked Eser's answer correct as it was accurate for my original question.

Comment: What if your value contains all three permitted values? Anyway: you wrote about looping your items? Does this work for you? If not, what error/result do you get? Show what you´ve tried allready.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (myString.Contains("Historical")) { .. do something } else if (myString.Contains("Correspondence")) { .. something else }`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere A good question, In this particular situation it won't as the strings are created programmatically from concatenated values.

Comment: @Equalsk Nothing wrong at all, was just curious if there was already something in C# which would do what I'm looking for all in one line.

Comment: I modified the question as I accidentally wrote one of the values as "Historical" when it is actually "Historical Search"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] permittedValues = { "Historical", "Correspondence", "Archived" };
string text = "Correspondence Vol 2";

var found =  text.Split().FirstOrDefault(x => permittedValues.Contains(x));
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere And it is what is asked in question :) `"Correspondence Vol 2" (should return "Correspondence")` Next time read the question carefully before downvoting anything

Comment: Eser's answer worked for my original question, even though I had introduced a mistake, so I am marking this as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

If it's always the suffixes that differ, something like this would work for you. Essentially, it says: Find the first `permittedValue` that has the same starting characters as my input, or return `null` if nothing is found.

```
    string[] permittedValues = {"Historical","Correspondence","Archived"};
    string input = "Historical Vol2";
    string val = permittedValues.FirstOrDefault(v => input.StartsWith(v)); // this will be null if there's no match.

    if (val == null) {
        Console.WriteLine("not permitted");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine(val); // prints "Historical" 
    }
```

Comment: Yes it's always the suffixes that differ.

Comment: I assume `Contains` would be better than `StartsWith` as it will also work if the permitted value is in the middle of a string. It won´t matter in the OPs scenario, though, just a hint. Anyway good (and right) answer.

Comment: Agreed, but `StartsWith` will be more performant for the OP's situation.

Comment: So is the difference between this answer and the one posted by Eser is this one is specific to differing suffixes vs finding the value anywhere in the string? (I'm just learning C#)

Comment: @ChrisYYC Have you tried both? Do they give you the same results?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I apologize, the order of the 2 solutions changed and when I said I had run it I had actually run njenson 's solution.  I just now though changed it to Eser 's and something is not quite right, it only writes to the log 294 of the ~1200 files, indicating for most a null is being returned.Hmm.

Comment: Ok I think I see the issue. When I mentioned "Historical" as one of the permitted values, it is actually "Historical Search". It appears Eser 's solution returns null in those cases as no Historical Search results are written to the log, perhaps the space in that permitted value messes things up.

Answer (score 0):

`Intersect` is another way to implement the routine:

```
string[] permittedValues = { "Historical", "Correspondence", "Archived" };
string text = "Correspondence Vol 2";

var found = text
  .Split(' ')
  .Intersect(permittedValues)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is very elegant. Re: my error I admit to in the comment of njenson's solution, what if the permitted value of Historical is actually Historical Search? your solution skips those due to the space in the value. Can that be handled with the Intersect ?

Comment: @ChrisYYC `Split` splits text into *words*. So This question and mine are based on this. But you change the rules of the game during match.

Answer (score 0):

This will return Correspondence.

```
using System.linq;

...
    var haystack = "Correspondence Vol. 2";
    var needles = new List<string>(){"Historical","Correspondence","Archived"};

    var result = needles.Where(n => haystack.IndexOf(n) >= 0).First();
```